# How to update table1 value with table2 value based on a table1 and table2 query?

Tags: mysql

I have two similar tables.  I'm combining/massaging the tables so I have complete and clean data in one table.  The goal is to retrieve Zip value from Table 2 and insert into Table1.

```
Table1
Mascot      City      Zip
Wildcats    Denver    MISSING-DATA
Tigers      Dallas    73843
Lions       Newport   53647

Table2
Mascot      City      Zip
Wildcats    Denver    98473
Eagles      Columbus  45362
Bears       Chicago   84739
```

My Pseudocode:

```
select table2 t2.Mascot, t2.City, t2.Zip 
where table1 t1.Mascot, t1.City, t1.Zip = MISSING-DATA
update t1.Zip with t2.Zip
```

I don't know how to write this complex query.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You’ll want an `UPDATE` for records that already exist in table 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an update join:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.mascot = t2.mascot AND t1.city = t2.city
SET t1.zip = t2.zip
WHERE
    t1.zip = 'MISSING'
```

In general, I would expect this approach to outperform an update using a correlated subquery.

Comment: Performance??? How many mascots do you think there are in the world? Besides this is only going to be run once.

Comment: This worked when I added "AND t1.Zip = 'MISSING-DATA'":  Thank You!

Comment: @user3672303 It usually isn't possible to test update questions on Stack Overflow.  Hence I missed that condition.

Comment: Subqueries corrupt. Absolute subqueries corrupt absolutely.

Comment: @Strawberry LOL :-)   That typo courtesy of Apple.  Amusingly, it fit brilliantly with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest to understand is a query using a *correlated subquery* (a inner query that refers to values from the outer query):

```
update table1 set
zip = (select max(zip) from table2
       where table2.mascot = table1.mascot
       and table2.city = table1.city)
where zip = 'MISSING-DATA'
```

There are more performant ways, but this will perform well enough, especially since your data size is small and it's a 1-time update.

Comment: In general, we should not be encouraging sub optimal queries here on Stack Overflow.  That _this_ particular data set happens to be small is no excuse, because perchance someone reading this question in the future might have a _large_ data set.

Comment: And updating with a correlated subquery is not easier to understand than a join, in my opinion.

Comment: @Tim but OP is an SQL noob. Understanding is important too. Also this totally portable (unlike your query :O ). IMHO update joins are harder to grasp.

Comment: I'll agree that your query is probably more portable than mine.  On Oracle, for instance, you'd have to use your approach.

Comment: I tried this, but I received an error of "Subquery returns more than 1 row".